# C# Code for get average Data value from SQL data

Tags: c#

`Hello Guys

I am working on Rockwell new software FT Optix. In that all scripting will done in C# only.
so
I need a code to get average value of a column from SQL.
I know how to get average value in text form but I want value for further calculation. so, need in int format.

Can somebody help me.

Code to get Average in Text form (It is working fine) -
But I can't use the final value for further calculation as value is in text form only.

```
`#region StandardUsing
using System;
using System.Text;
using UAManagedCore;
using Store = FTOptix.Store;
#endregion

public class QueryResultLabelLogic : FTOptix.NetLogic.BaseNetLogic
{
    public override void Start()
    {
        // Insert code to be executed when the user-defined logic is started
        periodicTask = new PeriodicTask(IncrementDecrementTask, 60, LogicObject);
        periodicTask.Start();


        longRunningTask.Start();
    }


    public override void Stop()
    {
        // Insert code to be executed when the user-defined logic is stopped
        periodicTask.Dispose();
        periodicTask = null;
        longRunningTask.Dispose();
        longRunningTask = null;
    }
    [FTOptix.NetLogic.ExportMethod]
    public void StartMethod()
    {
        periodicTask.Start();
        

    }

    [FTOptix.NetLogic.ExportMethod]
    public void StopMethod()
    {
        periodicTask.Cancel();

    }

    private void IncrementDecrementTask()
    {
        var project = FTOptix.HMIProject.Project.Current;
        var myStore = project.GetObject("DataStores").Get<Store.Store>("ODBCDatabase");
        object[,] resultSet;
        string[] header;

        var Runn = LogicObject.Owner as FTOptix.UI.Label;

        myStore.Query("SELECT AVG(Actual_Speed) FROM OEEDataLogging", out header, out resultSet);

        if (resultSet.Rank != 2)
            return;

        var rowCount = resultSet != null ? resultSet.GetLength(0) : 0;
        var columnCount = header != null ? header.Length : 0;

        if (rowCount > 0 && columnCount > 0)
        {
            var column1 = Convert.ToInt32(resultSet[0, 0]);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(" ");

            sb.Append(column1);

            var queryResultLabel = LogicObject.Owner as FTOptix.UI.Label;
            queryResultLabel.Text = sb.ToString();

        }


    }

    private PeriodicTask periodicTask;
    private LongRunningTask longRunningTask;
}``
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what you mean.  This code appears to already be selecting an `AVG()` value from the database.  And the description makes it sound like that's working as expected.  What specifically is the problem?  Is the code shown *not* working as expected in some way?  Which specific operation in the code shown are you referring to and what specific problem are you observing?

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like the AVG result is already extracted as an integer into the `column1` variable.